# Dynamically hiding/showing form fields

Tags: 8

I have created a custom module in Drupal 8. There should be some fields invisible by default; when a user clicks on *More Options*, the field should display. When user clicks on *Fewer Option*, the fields should be hidden again.

How can I achieve this in a Drupal 8 form?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>   When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.

[image: Conditional Fields]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the states API as described in [`drupal_process_states()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x), which should not be confused with the [state API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/state_api/8.2.x).

The only difference with your description is that *Show more* is a checkbox, and the extra fields you want to show would be visible when the checkbox is checked (which also means they would be invisible when the checkbox is not checked).