# Show admin field based on field value

Tags: 8, users, forms

In the admin of a certain Content type (`node/31/edit`), I Added a select list field `field_hero` with two key|value's:

```
carousel|Carousel
video|Video
```

1. when the site editor select `carousel`, I want to display/show the `field_carousel` (an Entity reference revisions field, Paragraph type, where the site editor can create and insert slides for the carousel)
2. when the site editor select `video`, I want to display/show the `field_video` (a media field, where the site editor can insert a Youtube video)

So long story short. For the Hero section (header) the site editor is able to insert a Carousel or a Video.

**Update**

I try using Form API #states. I tried the following:

```
function my_theme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form['#id'] == 'node-landing-page-edit-form') {

    $form['field_carousel'] = array(
      '#states' => array(
        // Only show this field when the 'field_hero' checkbox value is carousel.
        'visible' => array(
          array(
            ':input[name="field_hero"]' => array('value' => 'carousel'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The paragraph `field_carousel` is of Type `Entity reference revisions`. Above is not working yet. How do I hide my paragraph field on the edit page using states?

Comment: The question is a bit too broad, which step is exactly unclear? First you need a form alter hook for the content type config form to add the setting field and a submit handler to store the setting via ThirdPartySettings. Then you need a second form alter hook for the node edit form to control access to these fields depending on the setting.

Comment: @4k4 I update my question and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: The updated question looks more like you want to show the fields dynamically, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199240/dynamically-hiding-showing-form-fields

Comment: @4k4 I update my question. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `:input[name="field_hero"]` -> this doesn't refer to the field machine name, but to the HTML DOM input element. Depending on your field widget this might not be an `<input>`, but a `<select>` or a fancy entity browser `<div>`... Look at the HTML code in your browser  developer console to get the proper CSS selector for your target field

Comment: Still not working. I tried `':radio[name="field_hero"]'` and `':select[name="field_hero"]'`. It is correct I have this in my `form_alter`, isn't it?